# Azure web app service deployment failure saying "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" after updating VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

**UPDATE** 5/18/23 - I updated this in Azure application setting from 6.9.1 to 18 (node version I'm using) and now I can deploy successfully again.

> WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION

**PROBLEM**

I'm not sure why my deployment is failing. I had this issue before in VS Code 1.65 to 1.66 and had to stay on 1.65. There was a VS Code update to 1.78.2 from whatever the previous version I was on.

I tried downgrading to the March 2023 version of VS Code and retried deployment, but still had the same failure. (FYI - still had version 1.78.2 open and running as I tried to perform a deploy using the March version) so don't know if that makes a difference?

Here is what I see in the output. I'm not sure what this means? How can I debug this? I have application logging turned on in Azure, but don't see anything in the log stream when I try to deploy. I also opened Kudu (*.scm.azurewebsites.net) and looked through the files but didn't see anything useful. Maybe I'm not familiar enough with Kudu to understand how to use it to debug a failed deployment.

```
    6:42:56 PM yoga-dev-1: Starting deployment...
    6:42:59 PM yoga-dev-1: Creating zip package...
    6:43:10 PM yoga-dev-1: Zip package size: 29 MB
    6:43:10 PM yoga-dev-1: Fetching changes.
    6:43:11 PM yoga-dev-1: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\qkztvba1.zip (27.71 MB) to C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted
    6:43:17 PM yoga-dev-1: Updating submodules.
    6:43:17 PM yoga-dev-1: Preparing deployment for commit id '7e83110e5b'.
    6:43:17 PM yoga-dev-1: Generating deployment script.
    6:43:17 PM yoga-dev-1: Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted" -o "C:\home\site\deployments\tools" --basic --sitePath "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted"'.
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1: C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\296456~1.8
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1: odejs\build\src\Loader.js:153
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:                 ...StatusLogger.DEFAULT_STATUS,
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:                 ^^^
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at module.js:669:12
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Array.forEach (native)
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1: C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\296456~1.8
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1: odejs\build\src\Loader.js:153\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:                 ...StatusLogger.DEFAULT_STATUS,\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:                 ^^^\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1: \r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at module.js:669:12\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1:     at Array.forEach (native)\r
    6:43:18 PM yoga-dev-1: C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\100.50331.6204\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\100.50331.6204\bin
    6:43:18 PM yogabandy-dev-1: ode_modules\.bin\kuduscript.cmd" -y --no-dot-deployment -r "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted" -o "C:\home\site\deployments\tools" --basic --sitePath "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted"
    6:43:19 PM yoga-dev-1: Deployment Failed.
    6:43:29 PM yoga-dev-1: Deployment failed.
```

**UPDATE** - Looking at my notes, on April 8, 2022 I had an issue with VS Code 1.66.1 where I was experiencing the same issue with failures in my web app deployment. So I downgraded to VS Code 1.65.2 and it worked again.

**QUESTION** - Is there something I can look into to see if there is some compatibility issue between VS Code, Azure and the web app I'm deploying? I checked the web app service and it's using .Net 6 as is my application. I rebooted my Mac, restarted VS Code. Not sure what else I can do to see if resetting something might help!

Comment: It looks like you're using an old version of NodeJS that doesn't support spread-syntax: `...` - or you've written invalid JS. Show us your `Loader.js` file.

Comment: Can you connect to the Kudu environment for your deployment slot?

Comment: @Dai hi Dai, just FYI - I'm using Node js version 16.14.2

Comment: How you are deploying your App.Could you please share your Code Repo ?

Comment: @Harshitha I'm deploying my app with the Azure App Service extension in VS Code. In the Azure resource tab I right click on the deployment slot and select "Deploy to slot" then select the folder with the published code. When I do this I can view the output window and I see the output above with the deployment failure.

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: Dai - yes I can connect to the Kudu env.

Comment: Check the version in the `.csproj` in the application.

Comment: Hi Harshitha. All of my .csproj files are using net6.0 and most of the Microsoft libraries installed (ex. EntityFrameworkCore) are using 6.0.1 and a couple of the logging libraries (ex. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) are using 6.0.2

Comment: I was thinking about upgrading .Net to 8 to see if that did anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253696/discussion-between-harshitha-and-user1186050).

Comment: The version of Node.js used by Azure during the deployment process may be different from the one you are using locally. Azure uses the version specified in the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` app setting, the node property in the engines section of the package.json file, or a default version if neither of these are provided.

Make sure that a version of Node.js that supports the spread operator (5.12.0 or later) is being used during deployment. Set the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` app setting in the Azure portal or specify the node version in the engines section of your `package.json` file.

Comment: @VonC Hi Von, I see my WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION in app settings is set at 6.9.1, but not sure how to look in package.json for this value as "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" isn't in it and all I see when I search is "node_modules/defaults", but not sure if this is the correct field? In it I see version 1.0.4. Do I need to add this field somewhere in package.json?

Comment: @user1186050 From your edit, I see `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` worked. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, the version of Node.js used by Azure during the deployment process may be different from the one you are using locally.

Azure uses the version specified in the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` app setting, the node property in the engines section of the `package.json file`, or a default version if neither of these are provided.

- Make sure that a version of Node.js that supports the spread operator (5.12.0 or later) is being used during deployment.
- Set the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` app setting in the Azure portal or specify the node version in the engines section of your `package.json` file.

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1186050/user1186050) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76258887/revisions):

> I updated `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` in Azure application setting from 6.9.1 to 18 (node version I'm using), and now I can deploy successfully again.

---

The [`engines` field in `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#engines) is not mandatory, and if it's not present, Azure will use the version specified in the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` app setting.
However, specifying the Node.js version in `package.json` can be useful to ensure that your application is always run with a compatible version of Node.js, regardless of the environment it's deployed in.

The `engines` field in `package.json` specifies the version of Node.js that your project is compatible with. It is usually found at the root level of the `package.json` file.
If it's not present, you can add it manually.

That would be something like:

```json
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
}
```

In this example, the `engines` field specifies that the project should be run with Node.js version 16.x. You can replace "16.x" with the version of Node.js that you are using.

The `"*"` value in your `package-lock.json` file means that your application should work with any version of Node.js. The `package-lock.json` file is generated automatically and should not be edited manually. Instead, any changes to the Node.js version should be made in the `package.json` file, and the `package-lock.json` file will be updated automatically the next time you run `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks for the post Von, where in package.json would this be located as it's a very large file? I did some searching but had too many results to scan through it. I did a search in package.json for engine, but nothing came up!

Comment: In package-lock.json I have an "engines" section where there is 1 value "node" that is set to "*" But overall the lock file has 713 results when I search for "engines"

Answer (score 4):

There's an issue with the `Node.js` Loader module, implying that there is an incompatibility or configuration issue with the version of `Node.js` being used.

Check the `node.js` version with `node --version` command and configure your environment as detailed in the below doc.

1. [Configure the environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node?pivots=nodejs-model-v4#configure-your-environment),
2. Update it to `Node.js` version `18.x`, Azure functions core tools 4.x & Function Runtime Version: 4.17.x,
3. Check [Visual Studio Code latest releases](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_78) and upgrade it.

In my local environment there is a `node.js v16.17.0` installed already. Once I created the `.js` function in Azure functions locally, I ran the function, it shows a warn as below.  With that, I also received the same error as you.

[image]

***Then, I updated it to*** `v18.0` ***and it started working as expected.***

*Note:* Before upgrading to any latest versions/releases, make sure that you are uninstalling the previous ones and install the specific release version.

[Install Node.js v18.12.0](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/release/v18.12.0)

After the above changes, I ran the sample trigger function with a Hello world message and was able to trigger it.

[image]

[image]

*Deployed successfully after updating with the compatible versions:*

[image]

You can also check the function runtime settings `FUNCTION_WORKER_RUNTIME`, `FUNCTIONS_ENTENSION_VERSION` and others in the application settings are set properly with the desired version values.

[image]

*Note:* Check that the version of the locally created function runtime and the version of the deployed function runtime in Portal are the same and do not conflict.

Once it is deployed into function app, you can view the logs from log stream in the monitoring section as shown.

[image]

*Or else,*

You can follow the below URL by replacing it with your function App name to retrieve all the logs.

*Log stream:* https://newaps.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream

[image]

Refer for [Azure Functions runtime Versions compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?pivots=programming-language-javascript&tabs=v4).

Comment: Hi my problem isn't with Azure functions deployment, I can build, deploy and run my Azure functions just fine. My problem is with my app service deployment. The app service deployment is what's failing! FYI - Using nodeJS v18.16, AngularCli 16.0.1, .Net 7 and VS Code latest. I believe all versions up to date. Is there some versioning I can check for the app service, like you are performing with the functions? I don't really see anything in my app service configurations, other than the .Net version, which have have set to Net7(STS)